# Date mask with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Looking for a mask where I can enter dd/mm/yyyy (with a limit of 31 for dd, 12 for mm) I tried several but possible to enter 24/24/2024

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean something like a regular expression that checks for correct format?

Answer (score 11):

I use [masked-input-plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) and handle validation separately with the rest of the form.

Comment: I use this too, it's straightforward easy to use.

Answer (score 4):

Try the [jQuery Date Entry](http://keith-wood.name/dateEntry.html)

> A jQuery plugin that sets an input
>   field up to accept a date value using
>   a spinner.

[image]

Description from [jQuery Plugin page](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dateentry):

- Can be driven via the keyboard or with the mouse.
- Accepts direct date entry via the keyboard.
- Allow various date formats including day and/or month names.
- Can restrict to a minimum and/or maximum date.
- Localisations available.

Comment: It should be accepted answer, since date mask really prevent user from input DMY(Day Month Year) from its maximum value

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one: http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/how-to-mask-input-with-jquery/

Comment: It's the one I tried where you can enter 24/24/2024