# Date format Issue using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In the below code i have a textbox my textbox should return a date format as yyyy-mm-dd.But it returns dd-mm-yyyy.Pls help me to rectify the issue.

js:

```
function Reportdate(txt, keyCode) {
    alert(txt);
    if (keyCode == 8) { txt.value = substr(0, txt.value.length - 1); return; }
    var dt = txt.value;
    var da = dt.split('-');
    for (var a = 0; a < da.length; a++) { if (da[a] != +da[a]) da[a] = da[a].substr(0, da[a].length - 1); }
    if (da[0] > 9999) da[1] = da[0].substr(0, da[0].length - 1);
    if (da[1] > 12) { da[2] = da[1].substr(da[1].length - 1, 1); da[1] = '0' + da[1].substr(0, da[1].length - 1); }
    if (da[2] > 31) { da[1] = da[2].substr(da[2].length - 1, 1); da[2] = '0' + da[2].substr(0, da[2].length - 1); }

    dt = da.join('-');
    if (dt.length == 2 || dt.length == 5) dt += '-';
    txt.value = dt;
}
```

ASP.net

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate"  onkeydown = "return Reportdate(this, event.keyCode)" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: can you provide an example of the value a person will enter into the text box?

Comment: Use better variables names, because I'm having a hard time reading it now and probably so will you, after not seeing this code for a month. Just an advice ;)

Comment: da=datearray dt=datetext. Not hard to remember. Also the date returned is likely dd-mm-yyyy and not dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @mplungjan Yes it returns dateformat as  dd-mm-yyyy but i want to return as yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: `txt.value = substr(0, txt.value.length - 1);` is not valid JS by the way

Comment: try with this code - http://archive.conductiva.com/en/blog/post/76/Improvement-in-the-Masked-Input-Plugin-for-jQuery

Comment: use this [link here.][1] you can modify this according to your need


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016299/date-mask-with-jquery

Comment: Your code does not work as it is so I suggest you find another